# What is "forever like a diamond" in latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

The question is in the title.
I tried several different websites for the translation but all give me something different and everything seems to be wrong.
The closest one was "Semper sicut adamas", but I'm not fully sure if this is right.
I had latin in school for seven years but this was a long time ago and I have no idea about the grammatic anymore.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is this a motto for something? The sense might be different in Latin depending on its context and usage.

Comment: The usage will be in a memorial context. someone is a treasure and in the mind of the people that are left behind, they will last forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation makes perfect sense, and it captures the English meaning very well.

I would perhaps use the phrase "in perpetua" instead of semper. It has a "into forever" idea rather than an "always" idea. That being said, I have read a poem that ended "Semper, frater, ave atque vale" where semper was used in a memorial sense.

Comment: While I suppose it isn't wrong to say *in perpetua*, the customary expression is *in perpetuum*. Alternatively one could also say *in aeternum*.